# Contract can't be mined in ropsten network

Tags: web3js, contract-debugging

I have a node running from `geth --testnet --rpc --rpcapi "eth,web3,personal" --rpcport=8545 --rpccorsdomain "*"` .

The contract is

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;
contract SimpleMultiSig {

  uint public nonce;                // (only) mutable state
  uint public threshold;            // immutable state
  mapping (address => bool) isOwner; // immutable state
  address[] public ownersArr;        // immutable state

  function SimpleMultiSig(uint threshold_, address[] owners_) {
    require(owners_.length <= 10 && threshold_ <= owners_.length && threshold_ != 0);

    address lastAdd = address(0); 
    for (uint i=0; i<owners_.length; i++) {
      require(owners_[i] > lastAdd);
      isOwner[owners_[i]] = true;
      lastAdd = owners_[i];
    }
    ownersArr = owners_;
    threshold = threshold_;
  }

  // Note that address recovered from signatures must be strictly increasing
  function execute(uint8[] sigV, bytes32[] sigR, bytes32[] sigS, address destination, uint value, bytes data) {
    require(sigR.length == threshold);
    require(sigR.length == sigS.length && sigR.length == sigV.length);

    // Follows ERC191 signature scheme: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/191
    bytes32 txHash = keccak256(byte(0x19), byte(0), this, destination, value, data, nonce);

    address lastAdd = address(0); // cannot have address(0) as an owner
    for (uint i = 0; i < threshold; i++) {
        address recovered = ecrecover(txHash, sigV[i], sigR[i], sigS[i]);
        require(recovered > lastAdd && isOwner[recovered]);
        lastAdd = recovered;
    }

    // If we make it here all signatures are accounted for
    nonce = nonce + 1;
    require(destination.call.value(value)(data));
  }

  function () payable {}
}
```

Deploy code is

```
const fs = require("fs");
const Web3 = require('web3');
const solc = require('solc')

const ethereumUri = 'http://localhost:8545';
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(ethereumUri));

let account = web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[0], 'password');
let source = fs.readFileSync('SimpleMultiSig.sol', 'utf8');
let compiledContract = solc.compile(source, 1);
let abi = compiledContract.contracts[':SimpleMultiSig'].interface;
console.log('Abi: ', abi);

let bytecode = compiledContract.contracts[':SimpleMultiSig'].bytecode;
let gasEstimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({data: '0x'+bytecode});
let contract = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(abi));
console.log('gasEstimate', gasEstimate)

const addresses = [
  "0xa90a595e286a992b575b9f2858a6725bc176c3f6", 
  "0x1a2eec7053a246c6ed8a75cf0f47fbed2bd7b211", 
  "0x03852aadab1794dbd472ae9ac772e79801d3bc3b", 
  "0x2349e11f56413ac91cc05a46341e4ea7992bedd3"
]
contract.new(2, addresses,  {from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data:'0x'+bytecode, value:0, gas:gasEstimate}, (err, myContract) => {
  if(!err) {
     if(!myContract.address) {
         console.log("Hash: ", myContract.transactionHash);
     } else {
         console.log("Address: ", myContract.address);
     }
  }
  else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Here is the strange thing:

When I run node `deploy.js` , it throw an error 'Error: exceeds block gas limit'. So I try to subtract the gasEstimate to `gasEstimate-5000`, then run deploy.js again, but the new error is `Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.` The transaction id is `0x4cb91d82c110a6bd198aa97691ae9844938a7dc7c8629468b39b704a688acbc1`. You can check it out on [etherscan.io](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x4cb91d82c110a6bd198aa97691ae9844938a7dc7c8629468b39b704a688acbc1)

Is there something wrong with my contract or deploy code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging with Remix shows the cause is probably this line:

```
require(owners_[i] > lastAdd);
```

Comment it out and the deployment appears to work.

Comment: I try to comment it out and find it still doesn't work. 悲伤...

Comment: Possibly try testing on http://remix.ethereum.org/ first and see what's the complaint?

Comment: I comment the `require(owners_.length <= 10 && threshold_ <= owners_.length && threshold_ != 0);`and it works. Still don't know the reason.